# Why does iTunes Connect sometimes offer an option to "Invite Testers" for Internal testers?

Tags: app-store-connect

The new iTunes Connect distinguishes between the internal testers (maximum of 25) and external testers (maximum of 1000).

At various points they say that newly uploaded builds are automatically distributed to internal testers via the test flight app, and this has usually been my experience. But *sometimes* I see a menu like this, indicating that I need to select "Invite Testers" in order for it to be visible to internal testers:

[image]

What causes this?

When it does this, I cannot distribute my build to my internal testers, and it seems like iTunes Connect is failing to recognize that my project already has internal testers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been experiencing this too. A hack that works for us sometimes is turn the TestFlight Beta Testing switch off, then wait for that to take effect, then turn it back on, and it usually pushes the latest out to the internal testers.

Answer (score 2):

Turning the "Test Flight Beta Testing" switch off and back on will indeed change the "Internal" column to Active. As @will suggests. The problem is that if you are already approved for External delivery, this will also cause the external testers to go back to the Submit For Beta App Review again, so use this work-around with care.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thank you for your input, but the answer you left would make a lot more sense as a comment on @Will's answer. Please read [answer].

Comment: Yes, I completely agree and understand, Engineer Dollery and Dijkgraaf. I wanted to post as a comment to @will's note. But couldn't because of reputation. I didn't realize you could comment on your own posts to build up reputation, thanks Dijkgraaf for that hint. Although I'm not sure how it would have helped in this case.